# How to pass commands to an SSH from subprocess in Python

Tags: python, bash, ssh, subprocess

I have used the `subprocess` module in Python 2.7.6 to establish an SSH. I realise that this is not recommended, but I am unable to install other Python SSH libraries such as paramiko and fabric.

I was just wondering if someone wouldn't mind just telling me how I'd now go about

```
sshProcess = subprocess.call(['ssh', '-t', '<REMOTE>', 'ssh', '<REMOTE>'])
```

I want to carry out commands in `REMOTE` with the subprocess approach. Is there any way to do this? Unfortunately, `REMOTE` is protected by a password which the user manually enters. If it helps, I'm running the Windows 10 Bash shell.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: At minimum, you should distinguish between `<REMOTE>` and `<COMMAND>`. How you're building `COMMAND` is important, too -- if you're substituting in variables rather than running a constant command, then there are security issues at hand.

Comment: ...your title says your question is "how to pass commands", but the only part it's currently obvious you don't know how to do is pass a password. What you're *trying* to do re: forming the remote commands to run, and how that's failing, is important.

Comment: It also matters -- a lot -- in terms of whether your Python program is running from a TTY where a user is present and able to interactively enter a password.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for responding. Yes, the user is interactively entering a password. I just realised my question was badly phrased. Basically, I am able to establish a connection just fine. But now I'm trying to pass commands into that ssh automatically once the user has entered their authentication details.

Comment: One option is to setup passwordless login for the user so that a password isn't needed. That's done by generating a key on the client and then updating the key on the server. For a unixy system, this is done with `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` but you'll have to figure out how your `ssh` client does it.

Answer (score 2):

Running a remote command is as simple as putting it on the command line. (This is distinguishable to the SSH server at a protocol level from feeding it on stdin, but the protocol in question is built for programmatic use, vs built for human use -- as the latter was the design intent behind the interactive-shell model).

By the way, if you want to run multiple commands via distinct SSH invocations over a single connection after authenticating only once, I'd strongly suggest using Paramiko for this, but you *can* do it with OpenSSH command-line tools by using [SSH multiplexing support](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing).

---

Let's say you have an array representing your remote command:

```
myCommand = [ 'ls', '-l', '/tmp/my directory name with spaces' ]
```

To get that into a string (in a way that honors the spaces and can't let a maliciously-selected name run arbitrary commands on the remote server), you'd use:

```
myCommandStr = ' '.join(pipes.quote(n) for n in myCommand)
```

Now, you have something you can pass as a command line argument to ssh:

```
subprocess.call(['ssh', '-t', hostname, myCommandStr])
```

However, let's say you want to nest this. You can just repeat the process:

```
myCommand = [ 'ssh', '-t', hostname1, myCommandStr ]
myCommandStr = ' '.join(pipes.quote(n) for n in myCommand)
subprocess.call(['ssh', '-t', hostname2, myCommandStr])
```

Because we aren't redirecting stdin or stdout, they should still be pointed at the terminal from which your Python program was started, so SSH should be able to execute its password prompts directly.

---

That said, *specifically* for ssh'ing through an interim system, you don't need to go through this much trouble: You can tell `ssh` to do that work for you with the `ProxyJump` option:

```
myCommand = [ 'ls', '-l', '/tmp/my directory name with spaces' ]
myCommandStr = ' '.join(pipes.quote(n) for n in myCommand)
subprocess.call(['ssh', '-o', 'ProxyJump=%s' % hostname1, hostname2, myCommandStr])
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, you say you can connect.  So after that, to interact over ssh using subprocess you will need something like:

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', <remote client>],
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
back  = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print error
else:
    print back
```

then to send commands, like list directory, something like:

```
ssh.stdin.write("ls\n")
```

Comment: `ssh.stdout.readlines()` will hang forever unless stdout closes (after which point you can't read more in the future).

Comment: ...also, going this route means that the SSH process no longer has a handle on the TTY (since you're overriding it with pipelines), so it can't directly prompt for passwords.